# Locking on transaction in centralized place

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following scenario:

```
public class LockingScenario {

    public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<Task>> BUFFER = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> LOCKS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final Object SURROGATE = new Object();

    public void bufferTransaction(Context ctx) {

        String transaction = ctx.getTransaction();

        Object obj = LOCKS.putIfAbsent(transaction, SURROGATE);
        Vector<Task> tasks;
        Iterator<String> it = LOCKS.keySet().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            if (key.equals(transaction)) {
                transaction = key;
            }
        }

        //minimize the case when there will be created useless Vector objects.
        if (obj == null) {
            tasks = new Vector<>();
            BUFFERS.putIfAbsent(transaction, tasks);
        }

        syncrhonized(transaction) {
            tasks = BUFFERS.get(transaction);
        }
        //... create task
        tasks.add(task);
        // ... 

    }

    public void finishTransaction(Context ctx) {
        String transaction = ctx.getTransaction();
        Vector<Task> tasks = BUFFER.get(transaction);
        // finish job here...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to explain a little bit here the code above, and its context:

`LockingScenario` is the class for a managed bean, which is accessed by different threads, which initiate different transactions. Each transaction have a unique number and many tasks to be performed associated with it.

**I'm facing the following problem**: I need to lock a portion of code which shares some memory between **many threads, sending many tasks for many transactions, which have to be processed by a managed bean (this bean can actually have multiple managed instances)**.

**Question:** Is there a better approach for this scenario? This supposing that my approach is correct (I mean it's not erroneous).

**IMPORTANT:** In the above scenario you should only think about `bufferTransaction` and the code above it. The code bellow is actually in a different managed bean. I put it there for you to have the whole picture.

Comment: So you're trying to create transactions identified by a name (the map key) representing actions (the tasks) which should only be executed by a single thread (the bean)? It's not clear what the `LOCKS` member is for, exclusive access?

Comment: @daniu `LOCKS` is created in order to minimize the creation of usless `Vector` objects. I use `putIfAbsent` method to check if lock is put.

Comment: Java 8? And the `bufferTransaction` method is the one you can change, right? And what is supposed to happen when the method is entered, but has been called already for the same transaction name?

Comment: @daniu Java 7, actually. Yes, `bufferTransaction` can be changed only. When let's say the second call comes for a transaction, it has to add the task to the `BUFFERS`. Later, all tasks for transaction have to be processed in bulk. I think that's your question. If you want to detail on method behavior, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can simply do this:

```
class LockingScenario {
    private static final Map<String, Vector<Task>> BUFFER = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void bufferTransaction(Context ctx) {
        String transaction = ctx.getTransaction();
        Vector<Task> tasks;
        // prevent creation of two Vectors for the same transaction
        synchronized (BUFFER) {
            tasks = BUFFER.get(transaction);
            if (tasks == null) {
                tasks = new Vector<>();
                BUFFER.put(transaction, tasks);
            }
        }
        // create tasks and put into Vector
        tasks.add(createTask());
    }
}
```

The task list retrieval/creation is fast enough, you can block the whole buffer for that time.

With Java 8, you would use

```
synchronized (BUFFER) {
    tasks = BUFFER.computeIfAbsent(transaction, s -> new Vector<>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the @daniu's answer is good, I would just want to point out that the code from OP contains a race condition.

In the bellow snippet:

```
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        if (key.equals(transaction)) {
            transaction = key;
        }
    }

    //minimize the case when there will be created useless Vector objects.
    if (obj == null) { // point 1
        tasks = new Vector();
        BUFFERS.putIfAbsent(transaction, tasks);
    }

    syncrhonized(transaction) { // point 2
        tasks = BUFFERS.get(transaction);
    }
    //... create task
    tasks.add(task); // point 3
```

you can see that at the `point 3` there can appear an unpredictable behavior due to race condition from `point 1`. Before a thread (let's call it thread A) tries to initialize *`tasks`* `Vector`, another thread can move on and acquire the lock at `point 2` before thread A can do this, and this second thred access the supposedly created `Vector` which can be half created or not created at all.